# Show that the set $V = \{(x,y,z)|x,y,z \in \Bbb R \text{ and } x+y=11\}$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

a) Show that the set $V = \{(x,y,z)|x,y,z \in \Bbb R \text{ and }x+y=11\}$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

b) Let $V = \{(x,\frac{1}{2}x):x \text{ real number}\}$ with standard operations. Is it a vector space? Justify your answer.

c) Let $V = \{(x,\frac{1}{2}x,x^2):x \text{ real number}\}$ with standard operations. Is it a vector space? Justify your answer.

In this question they did not give me values of $x$ so how can I deal with it? How can I solve it?

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a). The zero vector $(0,0,0)$ is not in $V$ - therefore $V$ is not a subspace.

(b). The zero vector is in $V$ - set $x=0$.

$V$ is closed under addition - $(a,\frac{1}{2}a)+(b,\frac{1}{2}b)=(a+b,\frac{1}{2}(a+b)) \in V$

$V$ is closed under scalar multiplication - $k(a,\frac{1}{2}a)=(ka,\frac{1}{2}ka) \in V$

Therefore, we conclude that $V$ is a vector space.

(c). $V$ is not closed under scalar multiplication - $2(a,\frac{1}{2}a, a^2)=(2a,a,2a^2)=(2a,\frac{1}{2}(2a),\frac{1}{2}(2a)^2) \notin V$ when $a \not= 0$.

Therefore, we conclude that $V$ is not a vector space.

Answer (score 3):

If $V$ is a vector space, a set $S\subset V$ is a *subspace* of $V$ if $S$ itself is a vector space, under the operations of addition and scalar multiplication from $V$. In particular we must have $0\in S$ for $S$ to be a subspace, so it is clear in all of the examples listed that the given set is not a subspace.